# How to find words enclosed in regex?

Tags: html, regex, debugging

I have the follow wing text on my html pages and I need to replace some words. For example:

```
"./images/delete.html"
"http.google.com"
this is a text
```

I have to retrieve the string with the following criteria:

1. words enclosed in a ""
2. words with ./images/ in any position (or after opening ")
3. words ending with .html

In my example, only the "./images/delete.html" should be returned.

Can someone please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex whch uses a negated character class `[^"]` matches any char but not of `"` zero or more times.

```
"[^"]*\.\/images\/[^"]*\.html"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dL7jZ6/13)